Pandas | style.Styler | How to format values in a row?
In the below code, a DF is produced and then some basic styling is applied (borders, changing background colors, centering text, etc.)
What I would like to do is format all the values at the index 'KPI DEF' as percentages. Some rows are to be styled as integer values and some as percentages.

Comments on some things explored:-

The code below already uses the Pandas style.Styler.format method to set target columns as percentages (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html) but this method doesn't allow an axis to be specified.

I also took a look at style.Styler.apply to see if a function could be applied to the target rows (similar to using apply regularly on a DF). However, the documentation suggests this method is only for HTML/CSS styling.



import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index(['KPI ABC', 'KPI DEF', 'KPI GHI', 'KPI JKL']),
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
                      ['North America', 'Europe', 'Asia'],
                      ['Weekly', 'Monthly'],
                      ['WK-01', 'WK-02', 'WK-03', 'WK-04', 'WK-05', 'WoW', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'MoM']]))


df.at['KPI ABC', ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WoW')] = 1.44
df.at['KPI ABC', ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'MoM')] = -0.24
df.at['KPI ABC', ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'MoM')] = 0

df.at['KPI DEF', ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WK-01')] = 91.21
df.at['KPI DEF', ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WK-02')] = 91.26
df.at['KPI DEF', ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WK-03')] = 90.77
df.at['KPI DEF', ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WK-04')] = 91.16
df.at['KPI DEF', ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WK-05')] = 91.37


mapper =  {('North America', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): '{0:.2f}%',
           ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): '{0:.2f}%',
           ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): '{0:.2f}%'}

s = df.style.format(mapper).hide([
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'Jan'),
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'Feb'),
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'Mar'),
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'MoM'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-01'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-02'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-03'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-04'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-05'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WoW'),

    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'Jan'),
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'Feb'),
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'Mar'),
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'MoM'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-01'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-02'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-03'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-04'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-05'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WoW'),

    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'Jan'),
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'Feb'),
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'Mar'),
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'MoM'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-01'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-02'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-03'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-04'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-05'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WoW')],
    axis="columns")

cell_hover = {'selector': 'td:hover', 'props': [('background-color', '#ffffb3')]}
headers = {'selector': 'th:not(.index_name)', 'props': 'background-color: #000066; color: white;'}
global_left_align = {'selector': 'th', 'props': 'text-align: left'}

s = s.set_table_styles([cell_hover, headers, global_left_align])


# BORDER FORMATTING ===========================
border_styles = {
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'}
}

for key, value in border_styles.items():
    s = s.set_table_styles({key: [value]}, overwrite=False, axis=0)

# COLUMN HEADER FORMATTING ===========================
s = s.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th.col_heading', 'props': 'text-align: center;'}], overwrite=False)

def larger_headers(val):
    if val in ['North America', 'Europe', 'Asia']:
        return 'font-size: 16pt'
    return ''

s = s.applymap_index(larger_headers, axis='columns', level=0)



You need to define a function for the formatting of values:
def format_values(val, row_index):
    if row_index == 'KPI DEF':
        return '{:.2f}%'.format(val) if pd.notnull(val) else ''
    else:
        return '{:.2f}'.format(val) if pd.notnull(val) else ''

So, your entire code will look like:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index(['KPI ABC', 'KPI DEF', 'KPI GHI', 'KPI JKL']),
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
                      ['North America', 'Europe', 'Asia'],
                      ['Weekly', 'Monthly'],
                      ['WK-01', 'WK-02', 'WK-03', 'WK-04', 'WK-05', 'WoW', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'MoM']]))

df.at['KPI ABC', ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WoW')] = 1.44
df.at['KPI ABC', ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'MoM')] = -0.24
df.at['KPI ABC', ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'MoM')] = 0

df.at['KPI DEF', ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WK-01')] = 91.21
df.at['KPI DEF', ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WK-02')] = 91.26
df.at['KPI DEF', ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WK-03')] = 90.77
df.at['KPI DEF', ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WK-04')] = 91.16
df.at['KPI DEF', ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WK-05')] = 91.37

def format_values(val, row_index):
    if row_index == 'KPI DEF':
        return '{:.2f}%'.format(val) if pd.notnull(val) else ''
    else:
        return '{:.2f}'.format(val) if pd.notnull(val) else ''

formatted_df = df.copy()

for idx in df.index:
    for col in df.columns:
        formatted_df.at[idx, col] = format_values(df.at[idx, col], idx)

s = formatted_df.style.hide([
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'Jan'),
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'Feb'),
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'Mar'),
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'MoM'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-01'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-02'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-03'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-04'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WK-05'),
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'WoW'),

    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'Jan'),
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'Feb'),
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'Mar'),
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'MoM'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-01'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-02'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-03'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-04'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WK-05'),
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'WoW'),

    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'Jan'),
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'Feb'),
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'Mar'),
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'MoM'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-01'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-02'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-03'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-04'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WK-05'),
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'WoW')],
    axis="columns")

cell_hover = {'selector': 'td:hover', 'props': [('background-color', '#ffffb3')]}
headers = {'selector': 'th:not(.index_name)', 'props': 'background-color: #000066; color: white;'}
global_left_align = {'selector': 'th', 'props': 'text-align: left'}

s = s.set_table_styles([cell_hover, headers, global_left_align])


# BORDER FORMATTING ===========================
border_styles = {
    ('North America', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('North America', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('Europe', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('Europe', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('Asia', 'Weekly', 'WoW'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'},
    ('Asia', 'Monthly', 'MoM'): {'selector': 'th, td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid #000066; border-right: 1px solid #000066'}
}

for key, value in border_styles.items():
    s = s.set_table_styles({key: [value]}, overwrite=False, axis=0)

# COLUMN HEADER FORMATTING ===========================
s = s.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th.col_heading', 'props': 'text-align: center;'}], overwrite=False)

def larger_headers(val):
    if val in ['North America', 'Europe', 'Asia']:
        return 'font-size: 16pt'
    return ''

s = s.applymap_index(larger_headers, axis='columns', level=0)

s


which gives you (did not manage to fit it entirely in one image):

The advantage of having a function added to this is that it fits with the answers I gave to your previous questions.
